# EF Scaffold-DbContext Reverse Engineering Table - Generates Invalid column name error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

VS2019, Core 3.1, C#

I reverse migrated a table from an existing DB:

`Scaffold-DbContext 'my connection string' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Tables 'Accounts'`

One of the columns is AcctSN (varchar(50), null).  It gets generated as follows:

`public string AcctSN { get; set; }`

Don't see anything wrong with this. (It's not a key and there is no index on it.)

I have everything wired up and when I call it

`var accounts = await dbContext.Account.ToListAsync();`

I get the following error:

`"Invalid column name 'AcctSN'."`

Here's the entire error:

```
    Class: 16
    ClientConnectionId: {REDACTED GUID}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    ErrorCode: -2146232060
    Errors: {Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlErrorCollection}
    HResult: -2146232060
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    LineNumber: 1
    Message: "Invalid column name 'AcctSN'."
    Number: 207
    Procedure: ""
    Server: "REDACTED"
    Source: "Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider"
    StackTrace: "   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__164_0(Task`1 result)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.Get
Result()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__17.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__17.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__17.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<InitializeReaderAsync>d__18.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServi
ces.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__17.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__64`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionService
s.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__64`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at REDACTED.AccountRepository.<GetAccounts>d__2.MoveNext() in REDACTED"
    State: 1
    TargetSite: {System.Data.Common.DbDataReader <ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__164_0(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader])}
```

This is a stand alone table. It has no relationships with other tables. (I did not build this DB.)  There are no foreign keys.  The class has another string property that successfully links to a varchar column in the DB; it works when I comment out this AcctSN field.

Any ideas.  Everything I've found so far talks about issues with keys and relationships but as I've stated above this is not applicable to this situation.

Comment: Are you using the same connection string in each case?

Comment: Yes.  I saw another post where the poster was not so I checked.

Comment: When you change the name of the property to a completely different name, does it still error?

Comment: You mean by using a data annotation?  I've tried ```[Column("AcctSN")]  public string AccountShortName { get; set; }```

Comment: Try renaming the column in the database then scaffold again. If it works, it would tell you the te 'AcctSN', as a name, is a problem. If it doesn't work, then something is wrong with your column. In both cases, if you can reproduce the problem in another project, you can submit a bug to EFCore team on GitHub.

Comment: I created a new solution/project and used Scaffold-DbContext to bring in the table.  That worked.  Started changing names around since the underlying db/table is really old and naming conventions are awful.  I ran into a problem when I added public virtual DbSet<Account> Account { get; set; } to the Context class.  When I changed the naming (public virtual DbSet<AccountDto> AcctSetup { get; set; }) it worked.  Not sure why that caused a problem.